# What maximum height of a 1 ton car when driven with 2500 kcal?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

It is recommended that humans ingest, daily, around 2500 kcal. If this energy could be used to raise a car with a mass of 1 ton, from the ground, how high the car reach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2500 kcal is about 10^7 Joules. 
1 ton is about 10^4 kg.

Your question reduces to at what height will this car store 2500 kcal.

The formula for gravitational potential energy is

U=mgh
So
10^7 Joules = 10^4*10*h Joule/m

h = 100 meters

Thus the theoretical height this car could be lifted to is 100 meters by 2500 kcal of energy.